# Li-ion battery applying more current

Tags: batteries, current

I have doubt that can Li-ion batteries in a non-turbo charging  smartphone be charged with turbo charge? In a nutshell, can we apply more current than a rated current in li-ion batteries? What will be the consequences of this scenario? How it affects li-ion battery? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean to remove the phone battery, and charge it with some other charger? Or else?

Comment: Most of the time it isn't, 1C charging is nothing spectacular. 1C meaning that a full charge will be obtained in less than an hour.

Comment: 1C does not mean charging in less than an hour.  You can only charge at 1C during the constant current portion of the charge cycle, as soon as you transition to constant voltage the current will be reduced.  At 1C, most batteries charge from full discharge in 1.5 to 2 hours.

Comment: I mean charging a smartphone which doesn't have turbocharge (aka) Fast charging feature by a turbocharger of another smartphone which has turbocharging feature. At Constant current state, does that smartphone's battery will draw more current than it's rating due to the availability of amps from a turbo charger?

Answer (score 1):

You 'can' indeed charge li-ion cells faster that they are rated for. 
If can means is it possible, yes. 
If can means, is it totally fine, then no.

When the battery is charging or discharging there is a transfer of charge at the electrodes. The charge concentration at the electrode then diffuses throughout the rest of the battery. This does not happen in an instant. It takes a different amount of time for each battery, hence batteries having different ratings.

So what happens when we do not allow for enough time for that battery to diffuse the charge concentration at the electrodes? You get lithium plating occurring at the electrodes; this is permanent. Enough of this and your battery will perform badly, if at all.